# All pages give a 404 error except my homepage

Tags: codeigniter

The homepage is opening properly, but when I try to navigate to other pages on my site I get a 404 error. However, when i Put index.php in the url the page *does* open properly.

In my config file I have set `$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";`.

Comment: If you want to omit index.php in your URL you have to use a [.htaccess file](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

Answer (score 6):

Inside the `config.php` file:

Change

```
 $config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

To:

```
 $config['index_page'] = "";
```

and create a `.htacces` file inside your root directory containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|fav\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```